# No se configurar nginx para aceptar las URLs de mi aplicación

Tags: angular, nginx

Os comento. Tengo mi web portfolio en Angular la cual funciona sin problema en su servidor de pruebas local (ng serve clásico), y si trato de acceder directamente por url a [www.cmfg.dev/perfil](http://www.cmfg.dev/perfil), por ejemplo accede directamente sin problema. El problema lo tengo cuando añado el proyecto a un contenedor de docker de nginx, lo subo a producción y trato de acceder a través de una URL a alguno de sus apartados, donde nginx me devuelve un 404. Puedo navegar perfectamente por la web en producción clickando por los apartados, pero no puedo acceder directamente . La web en cuestión es la anteriormente mentada [www.cmfg.dev](http://www.cmfg.dev) , y en caso de tratar de acceder, por ejemplo a [www.cmfg.dev/rrss](http://www.cmfg.dev/rrss) ya falla. Enésimas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras seguir indagando por mi lado, encontré una solución la cual copio y pego de otro portal:

---

Espero que sepas exactamente cuál es el problema. Este problema ocurre en SPA (Aplicaciones de página única). La url que escribe busca el directorio de página/archivo sabio. Si vas a digamos mywebsiteurl/radar-input buscará el archivo radar-input. En los SPA solo hay un archivo y eso es index.html para que no encuentre el radar-input archiva y lanza un 404.

Los SPA tienen toda su lógica, el enrutamiento en index.html y una vez que se sirve, maneja todo por usted (no en el caso de los que no son spa), así que si va a mywebsiteurl/ simplemente funcionará bien y todas las URL se cargarán a través del enrutamiento de la aplicación debido a que mywebsiteurl/ buscará index.html archivar y encontrarlo y servir eso. Entonces, si su sitio web funciona bien al visitar la URL base, significa que sus archivos estáticos están en el directorio correcto, solo necesita agregar esto nginx.conf

```
location / {
try_files  $uri /index.html;        #check if uri exists else serve index.html as rewrite
}
```

que básicamente intenta encontrar primero el archivo en la url, si no existe, servirá el index.html.

---